# Count triplets that sum to a given value using Binary Search

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

Is it possible to solve this problem "Find a triplet that sum to a given value"https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/

using binary search? Also instead of finding the triplets, we would count them and print them out. I know there are different ways to solve it for example using 3 for loops, HashMaps, LinkList, etc but I want to know if it would be possible to use binary search.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use two loops and a binary search in place of hash table for an O(n^2*log n) solution.

Comment: Thanks Dasblinkenlight. The binary search would be inside of the two loops I imagine... Using the For loops interaction as the left or right in the binary search correct? I'm a freshman on this :).

Answer (score 0):

Binary search could be used after sorting the input array, as such:

```
def find3Numbers(A, arr_size, sum):

    count = 0

    A.sort()

    for i in range(0, arr_size-1):
        for j in range(i + 1, arr_size):
            needed_3rd_num = sum - A[i] - A[j]
            if(binarySearch(A, needed_3rd_num, start_index=j + 1)):
                print "found numbers : " + A[i] + " " + A[j] + " " + needed_3rd_num
                count = count + 1
    return count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mnistic! So, I would need to substract the difference from I and J from the value we are looking correct? Then send the info to the binary search function to do the rest of the job. Would I insert an increment variable on the binary serch function to count for the number of triplets it finds? Or maybe I can create a function that counts how many times we get a return true Boolean from the needed_3rd_num function. What do you think? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Just noticed you wanted to count the numbers, edited the answer. needed_3rd_num is not a function, it's just a variable that holds the value you know you need

Comment: I'm sorry! I meant to return true boolean from the binary search function not the needed_3rd_num. Thanks a lot! I will go ahead and try it out and make sure I understand every step and logic. Thanks again.